# MySQL Query exclude item when Null

Tags: django, database

I have this issue in my Query which is I can't perform the actual output that I expected, so let  say I have this all data in my table named `Tev_incoming`

```
ID      code             slashed_out        status   
1   23-09-00001                                1    
2   23-09-00002                                1    
3   23-09-00003  2023-09-18 22:45:46.099847    3    
4   23-09-00004  2023-09-18 22:42:14.785251    3    
5   23-09-00005                                2    
8   23-09-00004                                3    
9   23-09-00003                                2
```

I have this query now

```
SELECT *
FROM tev_incoming t1
WHERE (code, id) IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT code, MAX(id)
    FROM tev_incoming
    GROUP BY code
)AND `status` IN (1,3)
```

**I have this result** to my query provided

```
ID      code               slashed_out                status   
1   23-09-00001                                          1  
2   23-09-00002                                          1  
4   23-09-00004                                          3
```

**Expected output**

```
ID      code             slashed_out        status   
1   23-09-00001                                1    
2   23-09-00002                                1
```

As you can see in all data there is duplicate code, it has two duplicate of `23-09-00004` I want to exclude `23-09-00004` because the slashed_out is blank which is status is equals to 3. I tried `MAX(id)` just to choose the max Id of the duplicate codes.  How can I modify my query , I hope someone can help.

Comment: can someone this? still I don't get the answer